# Issue decoding JSON URL in Python

Tags: python, json, time-series, urllib2, timeserieschart

I need to extract time series data (timestamp, value) from the url mentioned below. I am using urllib2 to get the data. I am able to extract data other url's that give a json response. However, I am not able to decode the data from the URL shown below. I don't have an option to change the API's response. Is there a way to extract data from the url somehow? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import ssl
import urllib2
import json

context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://localhost/app?json={"requests":[{"message":"GetHist","id":"XYZ"}]}', context=context)
data = json.load(response)   
print data
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-aaa819691ae6> in <module>()
      6 
      7 response = urllib2.urlopen('https://localhost/app?json={"requests":[{"message":"GetHist","id":"XYZ"}]}', context=context)
----> 8 data = json.loads(response.read())
      9 print data

C:\Users\k2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.pyc in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    337             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    338             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 339         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    340     if cls is None:
    341         cls = JSONDecoder

C:\Users\k2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.pyc in decode(self, s, _w)
    362 
    363         """
--> 364         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    365         end = _w(s, end).end()
    366         if end != len(s):

C:\Users\k2\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.pyc in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    380             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    381         except StopIteration:
--> 382             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
    383         return obj, end

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Data reponse from URL:

```
{ "responses" : [
{
  "message" : "GetHist",
  "id" : "XYZ",
  "rows" : [
    [
      "2016-04-14T00:00:00.000+05:30",
      "80000.0",
      "ok"
    ],
    [
      "2016-04-14T00:15:00.000+05:30",
      "79652.83966064453",
      "ok"
    ],
    [
      "2016-04-14T00:30:00.000+05:30",
      "86999.9008178711",
      "ok"
    ],
    [
      "2016-04-14T00:45:00.000+05:30",
      "80000.0",
      "ok"
    ],
    [
      "2016-04-14T01:00:00.000+05:30",
      "86078.55987548828",
      "ok"
    ]
 ]
}
]}
```

Comment: did you tried using `json.loads` instead of `json.load`?

Comment: Can you show the full traceback, not just the last part of it? If the `response` object you're getting from `urlopen` has the data you show, it should be read properly by `json.load`. Perhaps you should call `read()` on `response` to get a string you can examine, then pass it to `json.loads` for parsing. When you pass the `response` directly to `load`, you can't inspect it as easily.

Comment: @Omar Tried json.loads as well, but it is still not able to read it             data = json.loads(response.read()).

Comment: @Blckknght Added the Stacktrace above. Its not working with json.loads as well.

Comment: what is the content type returned by your call to localhost?  `res.info().type`

Comment: @miah It's returning "text/html". Is that the issue, that its not a true JSON response? As I wont be able to change the API, can this "text/html" response be used somehow?

Comment: `k = json.dumps(response.read()) //Change
data = json.loads(k)` Miah I am able to get the response now. It's showing me the login page code. If I am logged in and typing this URL in browser, I am getting the timeseries data shown above. But from Python I am getting login page html code for the same.

Comment: So, if you didn't get there already, you need to login (most likely with a session), with the Python client, and then you can go about your business as you expect